# symfony change from service.yml to service.xml in bundle

Tags: xml, symfony, service, yaml

Is there a way to change the actual settings from service.yml to service.xml into a bundle? When I created the bundle, I defined yml as al standard form, now I need to switch to xml for the reason that there where existing services. xml files which I would like to use without transforming them (which would work as well I think).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can switch to XML if you want to and have the config files in place. Take a look at your bundle's `Extension` class located somewhere under `YourBundle/DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php`. Its `load` method should look like this:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

To use XML configs instead of YAMLs, instantiate an [`XmlFileLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php) instead of [`YamlFileLoader`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php) (the parameters would be the same), and fix the `$loader->load()` method call so that it receives your configuration file name:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');
}
```

Comment: Yeahs thanx a lot. This helped me forward. I didn't recognize the Config File until you bring me onto it.... Well explained, no I understand.Thx